# How to create a table and map True/False if dates collide

Tags: python, pandas

I have to a list and a table with me
ID List:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And I have the dates they have logged

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to create a table in pandas with all the dates in the month of August and mark true or false if the dates are covered in the from and to date.
Please note that in this table all the IDs will appear (based on the first list) but in the dates logged it is not necessary to have all the IDs. Like 9 and 10 is not there in this example)

I have only kept till August 12 in this picture but it will have 1 to 31st August.

[image]

The dates logged in CSV format for ease of use

```
ID,From,To
7,01-08-2022,01-08-2022
4,02-08-2022,03-08-2022
1,03-08-2022,04-08-2022
8,04-08-2022,06-08-2022
4,04-08-2022,04-08-2022
7,04-08-2022,06-08-2022
3,07-08-2022,10-08-2022
6,07-08-2022,09-08-2022
1,07-08-2022,09-08-2022
2,09-08-2022,12-08-2022
8,09-08-2022,11-08-2022
5,10-08-2022,12-08-2022
6,10-08-2022,12-08-2022
3,11-08-2022,11-08-2022
2,14-08-2022,15-08-2022
5,15-08-2022,17-08-2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `date_range`, `explode`, and `pivot_table`:

```
(pd
 # for each row create a list of all dates
 # between "From" and "To"
 # add a new column with the default value True
 .DataFrame({'date': [pd.date_range(a, b, freq='d')
                      for a,b in zip(df['From'], df['To'])],
             'ID': df['ID'], 'value': True})
 # explode the list into individual rows
 .explode('date')
 # reshape to wide format with dates as columns
 # fill the missing values with False
 .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='date', values='value',
              aggfunc='first', fill_value=False)
)
```

output (5 first columns only):

```
date  2022-01-08  2022-02-08  2022-02-09  2022-02-10  2022-02-11
ID                                                              
1          False       False       False       False       False
2          False       False       False       False       False
3          False       False       False       False       False
4          False        True        True        True        True
5          False       False       False       False       False
6          False       False       False       False       False
7           True       False       False       False       False
8          False       False       False       False       False
```